# WinSCP get file creation date

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am using WinSCP for .NET library. I am facing some problems which I cannot resolve since almost day. What I would like to achieve is to get file name creation date. Do you know how can  achieve that? I am completely stack.

Tried like this but unfortunately source contains not whole path to ftp folder like

```
C:\folder1\folder2\file
```

but it takes folder2 as root ftp folder

```
session.GetFiles(source, destination, removeSource).Check()
```

If I would have entire path to file I would just simple use:

```
File.GetCreationTime(source)
```

Comment: Noone here can help you, if you don't show the code you use and state out the problem with it.

Comment: what can i show if i dont have nothing

Comment: If you have doen nothing, we can't help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Dim sessionOptions As New WinSCP.SessionOptions With { ... initialize your ftp parameters here ... }

Using session As WinSCP.Session = New WinSCP.Session

    session.Open(sessionOptions)

    Dim fileInfos As WinSCP.RemoteDirectoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(ftpFolder)

    For Each ftpFile As WinSCP.RemoteFileInfo In fileInfos.Files
        ' Here you get the file date:
        Dim fileDate As Date = ftpFile.LastWriteTime
    Next

End Using
```

Comment: yes this was i was looking for - by the way i found out it before seeing that post. LastWriteTime was the answer. By the way funny thing is that the real date of createion file is not Created Date but Last modified.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve attributes (including the last modification time) of a single file use [`Session.GetFileInfo` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfileinfo):

```
session.GetFileInfo(source).LastWriteTime
```

There's no way to retrieve "creation" time, just the "last modification" time.